# Android studio 3.6.3 cannot start basic activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android studio and Android development, I just installed the Android Studio, am using a tutorial from pluralsight.com. When I try to create a new project using the Basic Activity option it just gives me a very empty activity as shown in the image attached

[Snapshot after gradle build is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fyPO.jpg)

Comment: What's problem you are facing ?

Comment: What do you want to have?!

Comment: I want to have the basic activity opened in the gradle build when its done loading @Black4Guy . the basic activity selected in the image here  https://imgur.com/Si1Yj8h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For, this view,

Go to **activity_main.xml** and not content_main.xml .